# Problem getting output of sp_executesql into a table column (SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, resultset

I have a table called QUERY_TABLE.
QUERY_TABLE contains queries of the following format (nothing dynamic, except the parameters in the WHERE clause):

```
  SELECT
     CASE
         WHEN COUNT(*) > 10 THEN 'Y'
         ELSE 'N'
     END check_ind
FROM
     DATA_TABLE 
WHERE date_y = @DATE_Y AND date_m = @DATE_M
```

I wrote the following script, to fetch each one of the above queries, run it, and put the result into another table - CONTROL_LOG_TABLE.

My problem is that the result column, STATUS_IND, should get either 'Y' or 'N' as values, but for some reason I have not figured out yet, it contains '0'.

Appreciate your help!

```
DECLARE 
       @DATE_C DATE,
       @DATE_Y           INTEGER,
       @DATE_M           INTEGER,
       @CHECK_NUM        INTEGER,
       @CHECK_ID         INTEGER, 
       @CTRLM_TREE       VARCHAR(50),
       @CTRLM_TREE_PARAM VARCHAR(50),
       @SQL_QUERY        NVARCHAR(MAX),
       @CHECK_DESC       NVARCHAR(MAX),
       @ACTION_DESC      NVARCHAR(MAX),
       @EXEC_SQL_QUERY   NVARCHAR(MAX),
       @RESULT_SQL       CHAR(1),
       @RowNo            INTEGER,
          @params NVARCHAR(100) = '@DATE_Y NVARCHAR(4), @DATE_M NVARCHAR(2)';
          

BEGIN

SET @RowNo = 0;
SET @DATE_C = GETDATE();
SET @DATE_Y = (SELECT YEAR (@DATE_C));
SET @DATE_M = (SELECT MONTH (@DATE_C));

DECLARE CURSOR_CHECK_ID CURSOR
FOR SELECT 
       CHECK_ID,
       CTRLM_TREE,
       SQL_QUERY,
       CHECK_DESC,
       ACTION_DESC 
    FROM 
       QUERY_TABLE
          

OPEN CURSOR_CHECK_ID;
FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_CHECK_ID INTO 
            @CHECK_ID, 
            @CTRLM_TREE,
            @SQL_QUERY,
            @CHECK_DESC,
            @ACTION_DESC;
       WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
           SET @RowNo = @RowNo+1
           SET @CHECK_NUM = @RowNo
           SET @EXEC_SQL_QUERY = @SQL_QUERY

                       EXECUTE @result_sql = sp_executesql @EXEC_SQL_QUERY, @params, @DATE_Y, @DATE_M
             
        INSERT INTO CONTROL_LOG_TABLE (UPDATE_DATE, DATE_C, CHECK_NUM, CHECK_ID, CTRLM_TREE, SQL_QUERY,
              CHECK_DESC, ACTION_DESC, STATUS_IND)
              values (GETDATE(), @DATE_C, @RowNo, @CHECK_ID, @CTRLM_TREE, @SQL_QUERY, @CHECK_DESC, @ACTION_DESC, @RESULT_SQL)


        FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_CHECK_ID INTO 
            @CHECK_ID, 
            @CTRLM_TREE,
            @SQL_QUERY,
            @CHECK_DESC,
            @ACTION_DESC;
    END;
CLOSE CURSOR_CHECK_ID;
DEALLOCATE CURSOR_CHECK_ID;
END;
```

Comment: Why would you expect `'Y'` or `'N'`? `@result_sql` is assigned the `RETURN` value of `[sys.]sp_executesql`. A `RETURN` value can *only* be a `int` value and it denotes the success of the procedure; `0` meaning success and anything else meaning failure. As `[sys.]sp_executesql` is successfully running, then it `RETURN`s `0`, which is assigned to `@result_sql`.

Comment: You're right... actually my question was supposed to be, how to add an OUTPUT parameter, that does not require any changes to the queries run (dynamic variable in the select)

Comment: If you need to add an `OUTPUT` parameter, you need to change the dynamic query. If the variable is declared in the dynamic statement, then adding it as an `OUTPUT` parameter would cause an error (so the declaration needs removing), and if it wasn't defined the query needs to be updated to reference the new `OUTPUT` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to move the `INSERT` into the dynamic query.

You don't need to actually change those queries, you can just concatenate the `INSERT` around it.

```sql
SET @EXEC_SQL_QUERY = '
        INSERT INTO CONTROL_LOG_TABLE (UPDATE_DATE, DATE_C, CHECK_NUM, CHECK_ID, CTRLM_TREE, SQL_QUERY,
              CHECK_DESC, ACTION_DESC, STATUS_IND)
              values (GETDATE(), @DATE_C, @RowNo, @CHECK_ID, @CTRLM_TREE, @SQL_QUERY, @CHECK_DESC, @ACTION_DESC, (' + @SQL_QUERY + ')';
';
```

Another way of doing it is to concatenate `SET @outputvariable` to it:

```
SET @EXEC_SQL_QUERY = 'SET @result = (' + @SQL_QUERY + ');
';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @EXEC_SQL_QUERY, @params, @DATE_Y, @DATE_M, @result_sql;
             
        INSERT INTO CONTROL_LOG_TABLE (UPDATE_DATE, DATE_C, CHECK_NUM, CHECK_ID, CTRLM_TREE, SQL_QUERY,
              CHECK_DESC, ACTION_DESC, STATUS_IND)
              values (GETDATE(), @DATE_C, @RowNo, @CHECK_ID, @CTRLM_TREE, @SQL_QUERY, @CHECK_DESC, @ACTION_DESC, @RESULT_SQL)
```

and you would need to add that output parameter to `@params` also.

> I'm assuming you have all your bases covered with SQL injection here.

Comment: Liked the first solution. Elegant! Seems to work, and I thank you....

Answer (score 0):

To capture a resultset from a dynamic batch use INSERT...EXECUTE to load a temp table or table variable.  EG

```
    declare @r table (check_ind char(1))

    insert into @r(check_ind) 
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @EXEC_SQL_QUERY, @params, @DATE_Y, @DATE_M
         
    INSERT INTO CONTROL_LOG_TABLE (UPDATE_DATE, DATE_C, CHECK_NUM, CHECK_ID, CTRLM_TREE, SQL_QUERY,
          CHECK_DESC, ACTION_DESC, STATUS_IND)
          values (GETDATE(), @DATE_C, @RowNo, @CHECK_ID, @CTRLM_TREE, @SQL_QUERY, @CHECK_DESC, @ACTION_DESC, (select check_ind from @r) )
```